# when hover on div1 depenting on if it is on div2 or not it should act differently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complicated scenario,

I have 2 div as follow:

```
<div id="id1"><div>
<div id="id2" style="display:none"><div>
```

whenever user mousehover on id1 the id2 appears so I have the following js code:

```
$(  "#id1" )
    .mouseenter(function() {

    $( "#id2" ).removeAttr('style');
      $( "#id2").attr("style","float:left;height:20px;width:100%;background-color:#F4F8FB;");
    });
```

But when user leaves the id1 ,  if the mouse is on id2 the id2 should be visible but if the mouse leaves id1 without hovering on id2 , id2 should be disappear.

Now I do not know what to do ? when I use the following code as soon as mouse leaves id1 id2 disappears no matter if I am on id2 or not:

```
 $(  "#id1" )
    .mouseout(function() {

    $( "#id2" ).removeAttr('style');
      $( "#id2").attr("style","float:left;height:20px;width:100%;background-  color:#F4F8FB;display:none;");
    });
```

Can anyone help? is it even possible to do that?(I also tried to use jfiddle but their server seems to be down)

Comment: Pro-tip: define those styles as classes and just toggle the classes on/off.

Comment: Sure I am just testing now:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Show a div2 when mousenter over div1 is over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759566/jquery-show-a-div2-when-mousenter-over-div1-is-over), unless you can provide a reasonable explanation of why this solution doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$("#id1" ).mouseout(function() {
  $("#id2" ).mouseenter(function(){
     $("#id2").attr("style","float:left;height:20px;width:100%;background-color:blue;display:block");
});

$( "#id2" ).removeAttr('style');
  $( "#id2").attr("style","float:left;height:20px;width:100%;background-color:#F4F8FB;display:none;");
});
```

On `id1` mouseout you use `mouseenter` on the `id2`.

Here is [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/xododocu/1/edit)